# High density serial interface nonvolatile memory

Tags: memory

I'm looking for a high density (>512Mbyte) FLASH or other memory device in a small package with a serial interface. I'm hopeful but I can only find sizes up to around 16 MB with serial interfaces.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing the way you can satisfy this request is by letting "serial" include microSD in SPI mode. Unfortunately it's very costly to sell anything with SD support, though. USB flash wouldn't be as compact.
Edit: As Mark says, there are cards that do not have SPI mode.

Comment: I think the easiest way to get a large amount of memory is going to be microSD card in SPI mode.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of doing this.

Comment: @lonetech why do you say it is costly for micro CD in SPI mode?

Comment: @thomas_o  you need to be careful with this, as in my previous experience, microSD aint microSD, larger sizes can pose difficulties and some fat16 implementations on the micros, for example CCS for microchip have been a little half baked in the past (this may have changed).  Writing your own fat16 implementation is a lot of effort, so I do advice using something pre-existing.

Comment: Microchip make a Memory Disk Drive which implements a FAT32 filesystem for PIC's.

Comment: Cost: The SD association demands membership to sell any SD compatible device, which costs thousands of dollars per year. Also, just because you use SD cards doesn't mean you must use FAT.. although the spec says SD use FAT, SDHC use FAT32 and SDXC use ExFAT, the cards are just block memories.

Comment: Wait, I thought you only needed to pay royalties if you made SD cards or you wanted to use the SD logo/name??

Comment: nope, you have to pay if you sell any product that supports SD cards, $2k a year last i knew, you have to join the SD association.  Additionally microSD cards aren't required to support SPI mode so make sure you check the cards you use.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for the reminder. Cards not supporting SPI mode complicates things.

Answer (score 2):

A quick digikey search with your parameters (>512 MB, serial) reveals these digikey parts:

- http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=TH58100FT-ND
- TC58DVG02A1FT-ND
- TC58DVM92A1FT-ND

(I would have posted 3 hyperlinks but I don't have enough reputation.)

Unfortunately, from brief reading of the data sheet, it looks like their "serial" interface requires you to use a lot more than 2 pins.  Also, they're non-stock items and there is no price listed.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Are there any standard I2C ones, or at least SPI?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen serial flash up to about 512mbit.

For bigger, I've only seen parallel NAND flash and possibly NOR flash.

Answer (score 1):

ST/Numonyx and possibly others do some serial NAND flash devices, and parallel NAND doesn't need a ridiculous number of pins as they used a command-based protocol. Remember however that with NAND you need to do error correction and bad-block management.